# Is there some meaning to the capitalization of names in this manifest?

Tags: air-travel

[This manifest](http://www.dephub.go.id/public/0506_001%20PAX%20AWQ8501.pdf) was posted in another question.  I noticed the capitalization of names is inconsistent.  Some are all caps, some all lower case, and some have the first letter of a name capitalized.  Notably passengers 41 and 42 have similar names but one is all caps, the other all lowercase.

Does anyone know if there is a reason behind the capitalization?

Comment: I'm going to guess it's how they entered their name when they booked online. But it's a pure guess.

Comment: Or it could be based on rules enforced by various reservation systems / sites which automatically change the capitalisation.

Comment: That's a [manifest](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/manifest#Noun), not a [manifesto](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/manifesto#Noun).

Comment: @NateEldredge Beautiful! I'd have called it a typo, but it appears I made the same mistake in in the title and body.  Fixed now.

Comment: Those were my two guesses, but I thought I would ask in case there was a known and less mundane answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The airline industry was among the first large-scale adopters of heavily networked computers. For this reason they have some *really really* old systems running in the nooks and crannies of their infrastructure -- even though the actual hardware is not from the 1960s, some of the *interfaces* still are, and even some of the software may be. (They work well enough for what they're doing; changing how they work for all participants all at once would be both expensive and horrifyingly error-prone).

Therefore some reservations still pass through interfaces that don't support both upper-case and lower-case letters. When data is fed from such a system to a newer one that does have two cases, it will usually become all upper case -- but for some of the gateways someone has apparently thought (correctly) that it would be easier on the eyes to convert them to all lower case instead.

Since tickets for the aircraft can be bought all over the globe, through websites and brick-and-mortar travel agencies using reservation system hookups of various ages, the passengers on a single flight will have their information arriving through a lot of different channels.

In the manifest you link to you can see that the PNRs for passengers 41 and 42 are not the same. So even though they sit together and are probably related, they booked their tickets separately, and probably from different agents that use different systems. (They have more family on yet a third booking in the row behind them).

---

What this doesn't explain is that passengers 30, 31 and 116 share a PNR -- but not the capitalization style! -- with 42. And judging by the sequence numbers they all checked in together, so why is poor Jie Stephanie sitting 14 rows behind the other Gunawans? That may be lost to history.

(Based on the observations I'd hypothesize that the check-in agents may have a button that downcases the passenger name, but only one of the several agents that checked the Gunawans in care enough to use it).

Comment: Just for context, that's the manifest of [a flight that crashed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indonesia_AirAsia_Flight_8501), and all the people on that list were killed (except the no-shows of course).  So maybe you want to consider the tone of your answer...

Comment: For an online booking the name of record is also going to be what the customer typed in, and may retain that case.

Comment: Pax 30 and 31 are flying U class (as is pax 116), but sitting in the A class section, so they probably got an upgrade, and there weren't enough seats (or they didn't have enough miles) to upgrade all three.

Comment: Wow. Re the no-shows, one family of five skipped because a relative was ill, and another family of 10 missed the flight because they didn't get the flight change notification: https://mothership.sg/2014/12/illness-in-family-missed-email-resulted-in-15-indonesians-from-2-families-to-miss-airasia-flight-qz8501/